# Calculate StartDate & Time

Tags: vb.net, datetime, timespan

I want to do 2 things with date & time calculation :

First :

I have a `LastSave` (dateTime Format). 
I have two controls (NumericUpDown / Format Decimal), one for Hours, the other for Minutes.

I want to start another save at a specific time this day at  : Today's date + Hours + Minutes.

What i've done isn't work, cause i can't convert to DateTime my setting DateDernièreSauvegarde, which has a STRING FORMAT.

```
Private Sub TimerSauvegarde_Tick(sender As System.Object, _
    e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimerSauvegarde.Tick
  Dim LastSave As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(My.Settings.DateDernièreSauvegarde)
  Dim NextSave As DateTime
  Dim Hour, Minute As Decimal

  Hour = My.Settings.Heures
  Minute = My.Settings.Minutes

  Select Case ComboBoxA_Toutes.Text
    Case "A"
      NextSave = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, Hour, CDate(LastSave))
      NextSave = DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, Minute, CDate(NextSave))
      MsgBox("Next Save at : " & NextSave)
    Case "Toutes les"
      MsgBox("Next Save at : " & NextSave)
  End Select
End Sub
```

The second thing :

I want to start another save every (Hours, Minutes) specified in the numericUpDown fields.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` class has methods `AddHours` `AddMinutes` and so forth. You can use those to calculate your new save time.